# Used for advice with tire damage - sidewall-damage tag

Tags: discussion

All -

I created a [sidewall-damage](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sidewall-damage) tag to ***specifically*** cover questions pertaining to sidewall damage. This will help us (and hopefully new users) find questions where their question might be answered and we can mark it as a duplicate if need be. We have a ton of questions on the site about sidewall damage, so hopefully this will help us keep them straight.

Comment: I've gone through and edited all of the questions I could find which I believe are pertinent to this tag. If anyone finds any others, please edit as needed.